# Alpine linux missing shutdown command

Tags: command-line, alpine-linux, plasma

Im on a smartphone with alpine linux & KDE desktop, running ssh in, and for some reason no one thought to put a shutdown aplet in a logical place, and even the shutdown utility is not present.

```
 $ whereis shutdown
shutdown:
```

nothing, ooh but I do have halt, but no man pages. well anyway, is the shutdown command provided in a package,available in source code that i can compile, or just an alias to the halt command?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `poweroff`

Alpine Linux init system has been described in its docs

[Alpine Linux Init System](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_Init_System)

Equivalent to `shutdown now -r` from traditional GNU/Linux systems:
`reboot`

Equivalent to `shutdown now -H` from traditional GNU/Linux systems:
`halt`

Equivalent to `shutdown now -P` from traditional GNU/Linux systems:
`poweroff`